# SDL2 not found when included in file besides main.cpp

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

Upon trying to include `SDL2/SDL.h` in a file besides main.cpp, I get an error stating `Cannot open include file: 'SDL2/SDL.h': No such file or directory`. However, when I include it in my main.cpp file, everything works fine.

**Project Structure**

```
/Project
--> /Engine
    --> /src
        --> /driver
            --> main.cpp
        --> /include
            --> engine.hpp
        --> /lib
            --> engine.cpp
    --> CMakeLists.txt
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(PROJECT GUI_Engine)

add_executable (${PROJECT} "./src/driver/main.cpp")

set(HEADER_FILES ./src/include)
set(DEC_FILES ./src/lib)
add_library(engine ${DEC_FILES}/engine.cpp ${HEADER_FILES}/engine.hpp)
find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PRIVATE engine SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main)
```

I figure I messed something up in `CMakeLists.txt` when adding SDL2, making it so that only main.cpp has access to it. This, of course, is something I would like remedied, so any help would be appreciated! I am using a CMake Project on VS2019 on Windows 10, for further clarity.

As a side note, if there is a better way to include `engine.hpp` and `engine.cpp` in CMake than what I currently have, information regarding that would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Upon trying to include SDL2/SDL.h in a file besides main.cpp" - You mean that you are including `SDL2/SDL.h` in `engine.cpp` and it gives you the error message? It would be expected, because `engine.cpp` is a part of `engine` library which is NOT linked with SDL. (Your last `target_link_libraries` command links with SDL the executable, not the library).

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, sorry for any confusion. I see what you mean, and that makes sense, but as a total newcomer to CMake, I don't know how to go about fixing that... Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: So you need to link your engine library with SDL in the same manner as you link the executable: `target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2)`.

Comment: Oh okay awesome, that seems to have worked... with a slight caveat. I know this is now beyond the scope of this question specifically, but now after a successful build, when I go to run the program, I get a popup stating ```The code execution cannot proceed because SDL2d.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.``` If you know a fix for this besides the recommended reinstall, I would be very appreciative, otherwise, I shall do some research.

Comment: You need to specify in the `PATH` environment variable the directory with SDL's dlls.

Comment: Would this be done in CMakeLists.txt, or elsewhere? Yet again, I apologize for my complete an utter ineptitude.